# How to make a textbox with only corners appearant

Tags: box, mathematics, rounded-corners

I'm creating a maths course, and i want to make an environnement for the exemples with a textbox and to separe it from the rest of the page I would make the corner of the box appearing like in this book
[image]

Thank's in advance.

Comment: check the tcolorbox package.

Answer (score 7):

We can do this without TikZ and without any LaTeX package. The `\pdfliteral` primitive from `pdftex` is used here:

```
\def\vingl#1{\pdfliteral{q #1 .4 w 0 -15 m 0 -4 l 0 0 0 0 4 0 c 15 0 l S Q}}

\def\corners#1{\vbox{\hbox{\vingl{}}\smallskip
   \leftskip=1em \rightskip=1em
   \noindent #1\par
   \hbox to\hsize{\hss\vingl{-1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm}}}}

\corners{%
content content conten conten content content content content conten content content content content content content conten content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
}

\bye
```

[image: vingl]

In XeTeX, declare `\def\pdfliteral#1{\special{pdf:literal #1}}` and in LuaTeX, declare `\def\pdfliteral{\pdfextension literal}`.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the `tcolorbox` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{test}{enhanced, interior hidden, frame code={
  \draw[rounded corners] (interior.north west)++ (0,-0.5) -- ++(0,0.5) -- ++(0.5,0) ;
  \draw[rounded corners] (interior.south east)++ (0,0.5) -- ++(0,-0.5) -- ++(-0.5,0) ;
}}

\begin{document}


\begin{test}
content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
\end{test}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Magician ! I usually use tcolorbox with classic templates found on internet but I never really took time to read the documentation. THANKS!

Comment: @d3vel You're welcome!